# Memory leak even though every alloc is released

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

The last two days I spent with hunting down memory leaks. I´ve read the documentation and searched the internet for good information (e.g. Owen Goss "Finding and Fixing Memory Leaks in iOS Apps"), but still I have too many mysteries to solve.

For example this piece of code lights up in Instruments again and again. I tried my best but can´t fix it.

```
- (void) updateUserDefaults
{
    // alloc temporary Array for object´s positions
    NSMutableArray *tArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // store locations of objects
    for (int i=0; i<[originalOrigins count]; ++i) {
        CGPoint foo = [self.view viewWithTag:100+i].center;
        NSString *moo = NSStringFromCGPoint(foo);
        [tArray addObject:moo];
        [moo release]; //?
    }

    // retrieve all stored positions for all objects
    NSMutableArray *zettelPannedOrigins = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"zettelPannedOrigins"] mutableCopy] retain];

    // replace with objects from this level
    [zettelPannedOrigins replaceObjectAtIndex:zettelAtIndexInTonebank withObject:tArray];

    // save
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:zettelPannedOrigins forKey:@"zettelPannedOrigins"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // clean up memory
    [tArray release];
    [zettelPannedOrigins release]; //?

}
```

What I think might be interesting for others too is, that I release what I alloc. But still it is leaking. This I can´t answer with the documentation. Or can I?

Comment: Don't release "moo" inside the loop-- you don't own that reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *zettelPannedOrigins = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"zettelPannedOrigins"] mutableCopy] retain];
```

This will have a retain count of 2, as `mutableCopy` retains it once and you are calling `retain` on it again.  Don't call `retain` here.

Remember, if you call a method with `new`, `alloc`, `retain` or `copy` in the name, you then own that object and the retain count goes up.

Comment: Sorry, you've posted while I was writing my answer, up-voted! :)

Comment: I put the extra retain because my app crashed sometimes when this method was called (the line under //save caused it). Zombies said I reference a released object. So I was thinking maybe mutableCopy is autoreleased before I use it. Therefore I put the extra retain. But the leak was there before I used the extra retain too.

Comment: If you are shoving extra retains into your app to make it not crash without understanding why, you aren't fixing the crash, you are just moving it to later...   every crash has an exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSObject mutableCopy];` will give you back an object with increased retainCount by 1 so you do not need another 'retain'.

```
NSMutableArray *zettelPannedOrigins = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"zettelPannedOrigins"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

This should do the job :)

Comment: How can I make sure the object doesn't get autoreleased before I use it?